# Handling of multiple accounts on android

Tags: android, account

Maybe this is a simple question but then I´m no programming guru yet either so I´ll give it a shot. I´m producing an app on Android in which users will have to create an account and log in, in the usual way. Every user, i.e. some kind of ID, for instance their username (and thus every account, which all must be unique) has their own set of attributes, for example length, age, email, etc. I get that all this information will be stored on a server/cloud and will be retreived through i.e. every unique ID but how do I handle this list of users (i.e. accounts) programmatically? What would be the best way to store this list of users? From my own (little) experience I´d construct a class looking like:

```
public class Account{

   public String username;
   public int length;
   public int age; 
   .
   .

   public Account (String username, int length, int age){
  // do some method for adding these to the server; 
  }

  // Methods for adding to server
  // Some retrieve methods and what else that may be relevant
}
```

This however seem too simple and now when I´m writing it down it and seeing it, it just looks ridiculous. But how do people set these things up? Anyone has any good links to any examples (good or bad, most important is to get a notion of how it is done) of some sort?

Please let me know if I´m not clear enough and I´ll try to explain further.

Comment: The recommended way is to use the AccountManager. A good tutorial can be found here http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Content Providers in android. This way, you can store all user informations in a database and retrieve them as you would like with filtering and etc.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html